# How to fix dyld: Library not loaded... Reason: image not found Abort trap: 6?

Tags: python-3.x, pip, virtualenv, manim

I'm new to learning python (and coding in general) and I've been trying to follow the directions on

http://bhowell4.com/manic-install-tutorial-for-mac/

to install manim on my Mac. Everything was going well until I tried using pip3 to install virtualenv. As the directions state, I typed

```
pip3 install virtualenv
```

into the terminal (using pycharm). It then comes back with:

```py
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/Python
  Referenced from: /Users/rdownie/PycharmProjects/practice/venv/bin/python
  Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6
```

I've tried looking at fixes from different resources, but none seem to work. I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling python3, updating brew, upgrading brew, etc. Some other potential solutions I'm not sure how to implement. Any help in terms a beginner can understand is much appreciated!

Comment: How did you install Python3? with brew?

Comment: Yes, I had brew install it.

Comment: How about running the command _outside_ of pycharm? Try running the command from Terminal.

Comment: Oh dang... I think that worked! Why would that make a difference?

Comment: I don't use pycharm, sorry, but I guess it has something to do with the Python configuration or paths of your pycharm installation. Check that it's using the same python3 you installed with brew.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same issue when I had `Python3.6` and `Python3.9` installed on the same machine running `macOS Big Sur`.  I uninstalled and reinstalled Python3 in the hopes that Py3.6 and its links would be removed, but this didn't work.

I then manually deleted `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6` and all worked as a

Comment: This did the trick for me! Thanks! (macOS Big Sur 11.1)

Answer (score 0):

Try with `python3 -m pip install virtualenv`

Comment: It gives me the same message:

Comment: You do not really need to install it, you only need it in case you had preconfigurations that you would not want to modify, see this tutorial I did:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uZj_GQc6pN4

Comment: I'll take a look! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I have been researching and the one answer that helped me was [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59006602/dyld-library-not-loaded-usr-local-opt-openssl-lib-libssl-1-0-0-dylib). For those that have the same problem but in MacOS.

```
brew update && brew upgrade
brew switch openssl 1.0.2s
```

Worked for me Catalina 10.15.4