# dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib

Tags: macos, openssl, homebrew, vapor

I installed vapor via homebrew and then immediately wanted to jump into a project by executing `vapor new Hello` but then got the following message back in the terminal:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/vapor
Reason: image not found
zsh: abort      vapor new Hello
```

I tried some approaches to fix this like uninstalling and reinstalling openssl via brew but that didn't work . Also tried something I found in the internet but nothing worked. I assume it has something to do with vapor only working with version 1.0.0 but not 1.1.1 and that's what I have. I guess I need to downgrade to 1.0.0 but how'd I do that? I'm on MacOS Catalina if that matters.

Comment: Support for OpenSSL 1.1 was added to Vapor: https://github.com/vapor/open-crypto/pull/75

Comment: This might be helpful for others: <https://stackoverflow.com/a/59224109/3776039>

Comment: I used this method to fix `/usr/local/bin/wget` (that was exposed by `plenv install-cpanm`)

Comment: Only this manual fix works for me: https://www.programmersought.com/article/30292378091/

Comment: An [answer](https://superuser.com/a/391716/38941) to a similar question about Postgres and pg_dump may solve this issue too!

Answer (score 1048, accepted):

**Update:** As of **December 2020** and beyond, `brew switch` does not work, so use the other answer by @angabriel:

```
brew install rbenv/tap/openssl@1.0
ln -sfn /usr/local/Cellar/openssl@1.0/1.0.2t /usr/local/opt/openssl
```

**Original Answer:**
Switch to an older openssl package

```
brew switch openssl 1.0.2s
```

Or, depending on your exact system configuration, you may need to switch to a different version. Check the output of `ls -al /usr/local/Cellar/openssl` for the version number to switch to.

```
brew switch openssl 1.0.2q
# or
brew switch openssl 1.0.2r
# or 
brew switch openssl 1.0.2s
# or
brew switch openssl 1.0.2t
# etc...
```

Comment: This is the best solution and simplest. Yet Homebrew will remove packages that are deprecated. Not sure when will this solution stop working

Comment: @Leopathu can you elaborate why this should be the approved answer and not the one I approved? If this is the better answer I still can approve it.

Comment: This one worked for me because I required a version of openssl which contained libssl.1.0.0.dylib. The latest version of openssl contains libssl.1.1.dylib.

Comment: This work for me with a little change the last letter "r" brew switch openssl 1.0.2r on MacOS Catalina

Comment: best solution. brew switch openssl 1.0.2t in my case

Comment: thank you I can't imagine how much time you must have saved me. My openssl broke after upgrading my Mac to Catalina.

Comment: I felt like @smokie deserved the upvote for being there first with the right approach vs. all of the other answers that just say which +1 letter version number worked for their exact setup...

Comment: On my High Sierra 10.13.6
`brew switch openssl 1.0.2t`
worked

Comment: just stopping to say thanks. i had done all sorts of weird stuff trying to get a one off project building and this solved my issues

Comment: thankyouthankyouthankyou! worked here with 1.0.2r. On High Sierra.

Comment: Wow. I thought I was screwed until I found this. Ran a series of commands to install Python/Flask, then all my RSpec tests were failing. Thank you...

Comment: `brew switch openssl 1.0.2t` Work for me on "macOS Mojave"

Comment: Thanks, `brew switch openssl 1.0.2r` fixed my `psql install on OSX (I use PostgresApp).

Comment: brew switch openssl 1.0.2r works for me, thank you. and 'ls -al /usr/local/Cellar/openssl' is the key.

Comment: I don't even fully understand this issue but this worked for me

Comment: I've just begun having problems with brew; and coming here and getting a holistic take on the behaviours... Am I alone in thinking brew is reducing as a valuable project? If it removes deprecated content, and I'm using various systems with dependencies that are merely a couple years old, and dependencies are dropped... If to resolve issues, the solutions require a manual investment in seeking sources and making... kinda makes the value of being a dependency manager moot. 
I need to talk in a community forum about this issue.

Comment: What should I do if I don't have any "older" versions installed on my Mac, but just 1.1.1g?

Comment: I'm getting `Error: openssl not found in the Cellar.` when trying to switch, any ideas?

Comment: When running `ls -al /usr/local/Cellar/openssl` did anyone get `ls: /usr/local/Cellar/openssl: No such file or directory`?

Comment: Same here, probably after an upgrade of homebrew it removed it.

Comment: @yegor256 how about `ls -al /usr/local/Cellar/openssl*`?

Comment: @Soyaine That just gives me the latest 1.1.1g

Comment: i don't think it is a good idea to *downgrade* a security relevant component as this.

Comment: Brew on MacOS no longer supports OpenSSL 1.0.X -- you'll need to manually fetch the older brew core from git, checkout the commit, and install the older openSSL libs from there.
See https://izziswift.com/openssl-1-0-2m-on-macos/

Comment: I have python3.8 that use openssl 1.1 and another virtualenv on python 3.7 that used openssl1.0. While brew install, it must have deleted openssl1.0. If i brew reinstall the old version and use "switch", would it break the python3.8 venv?

Comment: "brew switch" is already disabled. So what then?

Comment: @deyvw: check out the answer below:
```brew install rbenv/tap/openssl@1.0``` | 
```ln -sfn /usr/local/Cellar/openssl@1.0/1.0.2t /usr/local/opt/openssl```

Comment: My (this) answer has become outdated, `brew switch` got disabled, openssl 1.* wouldn't be installed out of the box nowadays. I suggest moving the correct answer to the one below (by @angabiel)

Comment: @BartJonk you should pull that out into its own answer, that's the correct approach

Comment: @Bart Jonk I agree with Anthony. That should be in its own answer. In 2021, that's the only thing that worked for me after trying a lot of different approaches

Comment: When trying to install openssl@1.0 on macOS 12.1 Monterey on a MacBook M1 the make command fails. Does anyone have a solution for that?

Comment: On Apple Silicon, Homebrew packages are installed in `/opt/homebrew` and not `/usr/local/opt`. Can create a symlink to it using `sudo ln -sfn /opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1 /usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1`

Answer (score 243):

**December 2020** This thread has many answers, but none worked for me. 
The top answer also suggests a downgrade:

`brew switch ...` throws `Calling brew switch is disabled!`

**this worked for me:**

```
brew install rbenv/tap/openssl@1.0
ln -sfn /usr/local/Cellar/openssl@1.0/1.0.2t /usr/local/opt/openssl
```

found here: https://github.com/kelaberetiv/TagUI/issues/86
(I need to run old mongodb 3.4 on OSX 10.13.x)

Comment: `brew install rbenv/tap/openssl@1.0` took forever! But finally a solution that worked for me using macOS Big Sur, thanks @angabriel!

Comment: Was facing the same issue when running `sudo gem install cocoapods`. This helped, thanks!

Comment: This solution that worked for me using macOS Big Sur, thanks

Comment: Worked on macOS Mojave fyi, thank you for the workaround!

Comment: This worked for me on High Sierra with `/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.20/bin/mysqld`

Comment: MacOS 11.2.3, worked like a charm, thanks!

Comment: Hours and hours trying to install cocoapods and I came across this and was hopeful as I too have an M1 with Big Sur but this did not work for me.... I get this: x86_64cpuid.s:273:10: error: unknown token in expression cmpq $0,%rax (with a ^ pointing to the %)

Comment: Worked in Sept. 2021 on Mojave (the only thing that worked).

Comment: This worked well for Macos Monterey  as well :)

Comment: After searching for a couple of hours to a solution for broken 'heroku pg:psql' on Mac Mojave with Homebrew, this is the only solution that helped. Thank you!

Answer (score 100):

`brew switch openssl 1.0.2s`

worked for me on "macOS Mojave", "version 10.14.6".

Comment: Thanks my Tableau 2019.10.3 was not opening in Mac OS Mojave and this command helped solve that!

Comment: `brew switch openssl 1.0.2p`

Comment: `brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies openssl
brew install https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/30fd2b68feb458656c2da2b91e577960b11c42f4/Formula/openssl.rb`

Answer (score 82):

Try to use `install_name_tool`:

```
sudo install_name_tool -change /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.1.dylib $(which vapor)
sudo install_name_tool -change /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libcrypto.1.1.dylib $(which vapor)
```

In my case it start working when I used `install_name_tool`. The order of the parameter is following: old value (incorrect), then new value (where you have your openssl) and the path to vapor (which can be easily get by `$(which vapor)`.

Comment: brew update && brew upgrade will upgrade all packages, it causes **HUGE** problem

Comment: You know, you are a diamond

Comment: yeah please remove `brew upgrade` from the answer @michal-cichon

Comment: @MichalCichon could you please explain what is the vapor? "which vapor" gives me empty result and command cannot be executed

Comment: @Zheden Vapor is a web framework implemented in Swift. Please take a look at the original question in this thread. If you don't know what Vapor is then this thread probably doesn't answer your question. If you use Homebrew to manage your dependencies, try Smokie's answer.

Comment: Thanks @musafar006. I didn't notice I copied a wrong path in the second command.

Comment: Why @Cronay is this still the correct answer? can u changed to the most voted ?

Comment: If you make a good argument, I do it. What's bettwr about that answer than this the approved one? I once asked this and nobody answered me, so I left it as it is.

Comment: @Cronay, although the question involved vapor and this answer's approach has solved it for you. I am sure, many others like me, came here after a certain setup stopped working due to an OS upgrade (in my case it was PHP7.2, after upgrading to Catalina, it suddenly stopped working and produced an error like in the title) - which means this question helped many many others - and that is great :)

Comment: @Smokie And what technical advantages has the most voted solution in comparison?

Comment: @Cronay, the marked answer solves an issue involving vapor, my answer solves the issue mentioned in the title (not being able to load the openssl library). both are correct answers in my opinion.

Answer (score 75):

first, list the details of the installed openssl version(or other programs) by:

```
$ls -al /usr/local/Cellar/openssl*
/usr/local/Cellar/openssl:
total 0
drwxr-xr-x    3 mba  staff    96 Nov 30 17:18 .
drwxrwxr-x  170 mba  admin  5440 Apr  8 02:03 ..
drwxr-xr-x   13 mba  staff   416 Nov 21 03:13 1.0.2t

/usr/local/Cellar/openssl@1.1:
total 0
drwxr-xr-x    4 mba  staff   128 Apr  7 18:35 .
drwxrwxr-x  170 mba  admin  5440 Apr  8 02:03 ..
drwxr-xr-x   14 mba  staff   448 Oct  1  2019 1.1.1d
drwxr-xr-x   14 mba  staff   448 Apr  7 18:35 1.1.1f
```

as above output, there are only one "right" versions "openssl" in my mac.
then, switch to it:

```
$brew switch openssl 1.0.2t                                 
Cleaning /usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2t
Opt link created for /usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2t
```

Comment: I spent a whole day installing, reinstalling rails versions, mysql2 gems with various flags and options. This worked like a charm! Thanks mate!

Comment: Thanks so much for this. What shows that 1.0.2t is the "right" version? I have a 1.0.2r and a 1.1.1d  and 1.1.1f.

Comment: `there are only one "right" versions` - what does this mean?  How do you tell?

Comment: i can see only 
/usr/local/Cellar/openssl@1.1:
/usr/local/Cellar/openssl@3:

my macos version is 13.5.1

Answer (score 59):

For MacOS 10.15 Catalina try to install the previous openssl:

```
brew update && brew upgrade
brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies openssl
brew install https://github.com/tebelorg/Tump/releases/download/v1.0.0/openssl.rb
```

Comment: Error: Calling Non-checksummed download of openssl formula file from an arbitrary URL is disabled! Use 'brew extract' or 'brew create' and 'brew tap-new' to create a formula file in a tap on GitHub instead.
If reporting this issue please do so at (not Homebrew/brew or Homebrew/core):
  https://github.com/tebelorg/Tump/issues/new

Comment: To install that GitHub link, we need to downgrade brew.
```cd /usr/local/Homebrew/``` change to version 2.3.0
```git checkout 2.3.0``` then install
```HOMEBREW_NO_AUTO_UPDATE=1 brew install https://github.com/tebelorg/Tump/releases/download/v1.0.0/openssl.rb```
https://github.com/kelaberetiv/TagUI/issues/635#issuecomment-699482920

Answer (score 53):

```
brew switch openssl 1.0.2q
```

MacOs Catalina 
Version 10.15
worked for me

Comment: I had to upgrade and update brew before this worked

Comment: Error: openssl not found in the Cellar

Comment: brew search openssl
==> Formulae
curl-openssl ✔                                                                  glib-openssl                                                                    openssl@1.1                                                                     homebrew/portable-ruby/portable-openssl

only 1.1 is available now

Answer (score 30):

I had the same problem.
I solved it by running these 2 commands:

```
brew uninstall vapor
brew install vapor/tap/vapor
```

It worked.

Comment: I just upgraded the client tool, not vapor but wget in my case. Which then used a later version of openssl `brew upgrade vapor`

Answer (score 27):

```
brew switch openssl 1.0.2r
```

it work for me,macOS Mojave, Version 10.14.6

Comment: It works for me (macOS Catalina, ruby 2.4.1, rails 5.2.2, openssl 1.1.1f). Switched to 1.0.2s.

Comment: similar works for me on macos high sierra 10.13.6 python3.6

Answer (score 26):

```
brew switch openssl 1.0.2t
```

catalina this is ok.

Comment: For me on Catalina this is working: `brew switch openssl 1.0.2j`

Answer (score 23):

This is the only thing that worked for me (OSX Catalina 10.15.7)

1- Download the file:

```
wget https://github.com/tebelorg/Tump/releases/download/v1.0.0/openssl.rb
```

2 - Run brew with the file downloaded:

```
brew install openssl.rb
```

Comment: or `brew tap cartr/qt4 && brew install cartr/qt4/openssl@1.0`

Comment: this worked for me, nov 2020 using "get https://github.com/tebelorg/Tump/releases/download/v1.0.0/openssl.rb"

Comment: Worked. Just manually downloaded the file.

Comment: just a fyi I tried the wget but got the following dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/wget
  Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6

Answer (score 19):

This worked for me on my mac

`brew switch openssl 1.0.2n`

Comment: `brew switch openssl 1.0.2s` worked for me on Catalina.

Answer (score 17):

i'll throw in my 2 cents because i didn't see an answer that resolved my issue.

my particular use case, relates to starting a legacy rails application using ruby 2.6.3 with postgres 10.x series.

- i'm running macOS 10.13.x **high sierra**
- i update brew almost on a daily basis, and the version of openssl i have is **1.1**

haven't started the rails app in several months, needed to perform some maintenance on the app today and, got some lovely ❤ error messages below,

```sh
9): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib (LoadError)
  Referenced from: /usr/local/opt/postgresql/lib/libpq.5.dylib

echo "and"

9): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib (LoadError)
  Referenced from: /usr/local/opt/postgresql/lib/libpq.5.dylib
  Reason: image not found -
```

the quickest way to work around my particular issue was to create a smylink from the current,

```sh
libssl.1.1.dylib
libcrypto.1.1.dylib
```

create 2 symlinks

```sh
cd /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/
ln -sf libcrypto.1.1.dylib libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib
ln -sf libssl.1.1.dylib libssl.1.0.0.dylib
```

**paths** and **version numbers** are obviously going to change over time so pay attention to the *path* and *version numbers* while creating the above symlinks. after the symlinks were created, i am able to start my rails app.

cheers

> leaving this here for future me

Comment: If this works for you, you should consider yourself lucky. The API between 1.0 and 1.1 was pretty different and most things that depend on 1.1 will not work with 1.0.

Comment: no such file or directory: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/

Comment: I think this is the correct solution. I did this a couple of times and it worked. I just forgot about it and end up here. So, just confirming this is a good solution that is future proof. Just make sure you create the exact erring lib version (1.0.0, 1.0.1, or 1.0.2), depending on the error you are getting.

Answer (score 13):

```
brew reinstall openssl
```

It automatically updates mysql server compatible with openssl. I tried many things, but only this worked for me.

Comment: This fixed it for me. Thanks.

Comment: For all the other solutions, brew seemed to need git (which is what was not working for me).

This is the only solution I found that downloads files and installs them without git.

Answer (score 13):

If anyone is coming for `openssl@1.1` issue in MacOS Big Sur,(i.e. `Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib/libssl.1.1.dylib`, here's what solved it for me-

```
brew install openssl@1.1
ln -s $(brew --prefix)/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.1.dylib /usr/local/lib/
ln -s $(brew --prefix)/opt/openssl/lib/libcrypto.1.1.dylib /usr/local/lib
```

Comment: To inform newcomers here, this doesn't work on M1 with a arm64 build of `brew`

Comment: Works for me in MacOS Catalina 10.5.5

Answer (score 12):

I had a similar issue and running the command below fixed the error for me:

```
brew update && brew upgrade
```

Comment: Simplest solution, openssl was in a correct and up to date version, but the stuff that crashed needed to be updated.

Comment: Fixed it for me.

Comment: saved my bacon!

Answer (score 11):

I had to downgrade OpenSSL in this way:

```
brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies openssl
brew install https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/30fd2b68feb458656c2da2b91e577960b11c42f4/Formula/openssl.rb
```

It was the only solution that worked for me.

Comment: Calling Installation of openssl from a GitHub commit URL is disabled! Use 'brew extract openssl' to stable tap on GitHub instead.

Answer (score 10):

Proposing `brew update && brew upgrade` as the solution is not a good answer and, as this error appears in most of the cases due the execution of this...

Switch to the previous version you were using with only: `brew switch openssl XXX` and that's it.

Comment: Guys from Google, the actual answer is here.

Answer (score 9):

A simple brew update && brew upgrade did the trick for me

Answer (score 8):

Mehn this is me in July 7, 2020, after facing this error for 4 hours. This is the only command that worked for me:

> `brew update && brew upgrade`

Comment: This worked for me on August 4th, 2020. As a note, the original, accepted answer had worked for me on July 16th, 2019 but did not work today.

Comment: This worked for me in October 2020. My project uses Symfony 5

Answer (score 8):

This worked for me:

```sh
brew uninstall openssl
brew tap-new $USER/old-openssl
brew extract --version=1.0.2t openssl $USER/old-openssl
brew install openssl@1.0.2t
```

Source: https://github.com/kelaberetiv/TagUI/issues/635#issuecomment-560138773

Comment: That was the only solution that did the trick for me. Additionally, I had to create a link so that Vapor would find it: `ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/openssl@1.0.2t/1.0.2t /usr/local/opt/openssl`

Comment: No available formula or cask with the name "openssl@1.0.2t"

Comment: As Andreas stated, you still have to symlink. But Andreas command is backwards. It should actually read `ln -s /usr/local/opt/openssl /usr/local/Cellar/openssl@1.0.2t/1.0.2t`

Comment: This worked for me, but you have to do --ignore-dependencies.

Comment: @LucasC.Feijo can you give the full command with --ignore-dependencies?

Comment: @iCyborg --ignore-dependencies is a parameter to the brew binary, so you'd call it like

`brew install nameOfPackage --ignore-dependencies`

Answer (score 7):

#### If you are using ruby-2.7.0 on MacOS Catalina 10.15

```
$ brew reinstall openssl@1.1
```

or

```
$ rvm reinstall 2.7.0
$ brew tap --repair
$ brew doctor
```

Comment: this hint saved me hours and hours, great advice for Mac users!

Answer (score 7):

Had this issue when trying to use LastPass CLI via Alfred on my Catalina install.

`brew update && brew upgrade` fixed the issue.

This is a much better optin than downgrading openssl.

Comment: This worked for me in October 2020. My project uses Symfony 5

Answer (score 6):

This might be a problem because of having the older version of brew and installed byobu which require new dependency in order to solve this problem run the following command

```
brew update && brew upgrade
brew uninstall openssl; brew uninstall openssl; brew install https://github.com/tebelorg/Tump/releases/download/v1.0.0/openssl.rb
```

Answer (score 4):

The above answers didn't work for me. I am on Big Sur 11.6 with Xcode 12.5.1 and the brew keeps giving me an error saying my command line tools are outdated. First step is to update Xcode to 13.0. Restart the machine, and then run the

`brew install openssl@1.1`

Restart the terminal and now re-run the command which was giving the following error:

`dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib/libssl.1.1.dylib`

Everything should work fine now, and you will not see the error message anymore.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue and based on this and other comments here's what happened and worked:

```
➜ brew update && brew upgrade && brew install openssl
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-dupes/' not found
Error: homebrew/homebrew-dupes does not exist! Run `brew untap homebrew/homebrew-dupes` to remove it.
...
➜ brew untap homebrew/homebrew-dupes
➜ brew update && brew upgrade && brew install openssl
```

This was after working on it for hours, but first time I saw the homebrew-dupes. Not sure how Homebrew knew what to install, but it seemed to install everything from scratch. macOS Catalina, zsh. I think the initial problem came because of Catalina

The error I was getting was:

```
dlopen(/Users/gscar/.gem/ruby/2.7.0/gems/pg-1.2.2/lib/pg_ext.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib (LoadError)
  Referenced from: /usr/local/opt/postgresql/lib/libpq.5.dylib
  Reason: image not found - /Users/gscar/.gem/ruby/2.7.0/gems/pg-1.2.2/lib/pg_ext.bundle
```

Answer (score 3):

**If you don't have Homebrew or don't know what is it**

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
brew update && brew upgrade
brew uninstall openssl; brew uninstall openssl; brew install https://github.com/tebelorg/Tump/releases/download/v1.0.0/openssl.rb
```

**Or if you already have Homebrew installed**

```
brew update && brew upgrade
brew uninstall openssl; brew uninstall openssl; brew install https://github.com/tebelorg/Tump/releases/download/v1.0.0/openssl.rb
```

This works for me on Mac 10.15

Comment: very good this worked for me.. when all the rest failed..lol thanks

Answer (score 3):

Above solution didn't work for me.

First run `brew doctor`.
if you see something like

```
Error: unknown or unsupported macOS version: :mountain_lion
```

then there are some outdated packages which needs to be removed, mine was
`mongodb`.

It could be `python@2`, `node@6` or some other package.

uninstall those packages `brew uninstall [name]`
then run `brew doctor` to verify if everything is ok.
Then you can reinstall those packages again after `brew update && brew upgrade`.

Answer (score 3):

**Explanation an solution**: It seems that you're required to install older openssl version that is no longer exist on current brew repository ( `1.0.2t version` ) . In order to solve it you should create a **tap** and **extract** an older version ( looking through repository history), after new installation create a link to this version and you're linked to the right version.

```
brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies openssl
brew tap-new $USER/old-openssl
brew extract --version=1.0.2t openssl $USER/old-openssl
brew install openssl@1.0.2t
ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/openssl@1.0.2t/1.0.2t /usr/local/opt/openssl
```

**Documentation** :

> Taps (Third-Party Repositories) brew tap adds more repositories to the
> list of formulae that brew tracks, updates, and installs from. By
> default, tap assumes that the repositories come from GitHub, but the
> command isn’t limited to any one location.

```
 tap-new [options] user/repo
      Generate the template files for a new tap.
      
 --no-git: Don’t initialize a git repository for the tap.
 --pull-label: Label name for pull requests ready to be pulled (default pr-pull).
 --branch: Initialize git repository with the specified branch name (default main).
```

> extract [options] formula tap Look through repository history to find
> the most recent version of formula and create a copy in
> tap/Formula/formula@version.rb. If the tap is not installed yet,
> attempt to install/clone the tap before continuing. To extract a
> formula from a tap that is not homebrew/core use its fully-qualified
> form of user/repo/formula.

```
extract [options] package user/repo
--version: Extract the specified version of formula instead of the most recent.
-f, --force: Overwrite the destination formula if it already exists.
```

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar error trying to run rails with postgresql. (I found this SO looking for a solution. Homebrew broke alot of things when it switched to open SSL 1.1.1) The above answers did not work for me (Mac 10.14.6). However, the answer [found here](https://dev.to/misselliev/a-note-about-openssl-error-on-rails-3jaf) did:

```
brew install --upgrade openssl
brew reinstall postgresql
```

Comment: `invalid option: --upgrade`

Comment: @AlxVallejo brew upgrade openssl

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve this by upgrading Python 3 via brew

`brew upgrade python@3`

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:
brew uninstall openssl;
brew uninstall openssl;
brew install https://github.com/tebelorg/Tump/releases/download/v1.0.0/openssl.rb

Suggested in this post:
https://github.com/kelaberetiv/TagUI/issues/635#issuecomment-560139279

Answer (score 2):

My recommendation is to never lower your openssl lib version for the sake of getting your build to work. Better to download the source code of the required lib and build it against the openssl version you have on your localhost.

I came across this posting while going through the same issue but was not comfortable lowering the openssl version come what may. Finally took the source code and build the app and it worked. I dont know why devs have their old versions of openssl on their boxes and which they build the dist packages and publish against those old version.

Comment: I agree with your concerns @Jerry and I hit upon what I think may have been a quicker solution than yours using MichalCichon's answer as a starting point. Good idea to rebuild from sources rather than downgrade your openssl lib version, but I'm guessing you know already that can be an extremely time-consuming process. Thanks for posting your answer.

Answer (score 2):

I have tried several solutions proposed above without success.

So, I have installed the last ruby version 2.7.2 with rbenv, and upgraded my app.

Then I had a `PG::ConnectionBad error.`

I ran

```
brew postgresql-upgrade-database.
```

And now It’s working fine.

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64666312/11410556) more details about what I tried.

Comment: Please share code with your answer and link at end for reference. want to avoid link-only answers in case that page stops working or changes.

Comment: This fixed it for me too, however the first time I ran it it did not. I had to `brew uninstall postgresql@12` then re-run `brew postgresql-upgrade-database` which fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this error with mysql (version: 5.6.46_2), Mac (Mojave 10.14.5):

```
    brew update && brew upgrade
    brew now setup_mysql
    echo ‘export PATH=“/usr/local/opt/mysql56/bin:$PATH”’ >> 
    ~/.bash_profile
    /usr/local/opt/mysql56/bin/mysql.server start
```

Answer (score 1):

I spent a lot of time trying all of the above, and nothing seemed to solve. Then I resorted the reinstalling ruby, and 2 minutes later the problem entirely vanished.

I hope this saves something else some time.

Answer (score 1):

I found this question after searching for the first line of this error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /opt/local/lib/libgssapi_krb5.2.2.dylib
  Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6
```

That I saw not from using `vapor`, but instead, as the result of using `ssh` and `scp` and `git` after upgrading some packages.

I think it's unwise to downgrade most packages as @Smokie and others suggested doing with `openssl` (especially for security-related packages).

So I generalized the answer posted by @MichalCichon on solving the problem with `install_name_tool` and that seems to have taken care of my issue (at least for now with `ssh` and `scp`; I think I'll be able to use a variant of this solution if the problem comes up again with another executable).

Because it was the non-existent `/opt/local/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib` library that was missing, and because I had a `/opt/local/lib/libcrypto.1.1.dylib` after upgrading, and because `ssh` and `scp` were referencing `/opt/local/lib/libgssapi_krb5.2.2.dylib` in an attempt to find `/opt/local/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib`, I just used `install_name_tool` like this:

```
$ sudo install_name_tool -change /opt/local/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib\
/opt/local/lib/libcrypto.1.1.dylib\
/opt/local/lib/libgssapi_krb5.2.2.dylib
```

Then tried running `ssh` again. It failed again, but this time with a different error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /opt/local/lib/libkrb5.3.3.dylib
  Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6
```

So then I did:

```
$ sudo install_name_tool -change /opt/local/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib\
/opt/local/lib/libcrypto.1.1.dylib\
/opt/local/lib/libkrb5.3.3.dylib
```

and tried `ssh` again. Again it failed, but with yet another different error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /opt/local/lib/libk5crypto.3.1.dylib
  Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6
```

So then I did:

```
$ sudo install_name_tool -change /opt/local/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib\
/opt/local/lib/libcrypto.1.1.dylib\
/opt/local/lib/libk5crypto.3.1.dylib
```

and tried `ssh` again. Again it failed, but with yet another different error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /opt/local/lib/libkrb5support.1.1.dylib
  Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6
```

So then I did:

```
$ sudo install_name_tool -change /opt/local/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib\
/opt/local/lib/libcrypto.1.1.dylib\
/opt/local/lib/libkrb5support.1.1.dylib
```

and tried `ssh` again. Finally, `ssh` and `scp` and `git` resumed working as expected.

Thank you @MichalCichon for a great answer that I was able to generalize beyond `vapor` to allow myself to continue using `ssh` without downgrading my `openssl`!

Answer (score 1):

After trying all your answers, it still did not fix my issue on my Mac Big Sur.
I tried on another Mac Big Sur and it worked for me. When try executing `which openssl` command to determine where is the OpenSSL symlink. It was `/usr/bin/openssl`, that different from on my PC is `/usr/local/bin/openssl`.

I realized that there are 2 OpenSSL symlinks on my PC.
`/usr/local/bin/openssl`
`/usr/bin/openssl`

I tried removing the current OpenSSL symlink

`rm -rf /usr/local/bin/openssl`

And run `which openssl` again, it pointed to `/usr/bin/openssl`

After that, openssl command worked for me.

Comment: One may break existing apps if they were referencing the deleted link

Answer (score 1):

there is/was no issue with the openssl version.
In my case the symlink was missing, so:

```
sudo ln -s /opt/vagrant/embedded/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib /opt/local/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
sudo ln -s /opt/vagrant/embedded/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib /opt/local/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib`
```

did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

For me it was that I had some old version of wget in my PATH. Removed it with:

```
/usr/local/bin/wget
λ  ~  rm -rf /usr/local/bin/wget
```

and then the brew installed executable had precedence and worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

on a macOS 10.9.5 machine with macports 2.8.0:

```bash
sudo -s ln -s /opt/local/lib/openssl-1.0/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib /opt/local/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib
```

helped

Answer (score -1):

I have `openssl1.1` installed on my system, but the rails is somehow using the old reference i.e `/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib (LoadError)` but this doesn't exist on my `Mojave 14`.

I tried the below solutions but no luck:

1. brew switch openssl 1.0.2t (Error: Unknown command: switch)
2. reintalling openssl
3. downgrade the version of openssl to 1.0
4. Reintalling rvm and ruby

**Finally, below solution works:**

```
cp /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.1.dylib /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
cp /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libcrypto.1.1.dylib /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib
```

Just copy the new openssl link to the old ones

OR

create the symlinks like below :

```
ln -sfn /usr/local/Cellar/openssl@1.0/1.0.2t /usr/local/opt/openssl@1.0
```

Comment: Did you read my answer? It states that I also tried `brew switch` and downgrading. "I tried the below solution"... Over time things did change. The accepted answer cannot be not valid forever when not updated. Also creating symlinks is better than copying around systemfiles.

Comment: Downvoted as it is incorrect to use 1.1.1 binaries instead of 1.0: underlying OpenSSL data structures are different and app built w 1.0 won’t work without porting w 1.1.1

Answer (score -2):

Had this error with mysql@5.6

Try to reinstall mysql

```
brew reinstall mysql@5.6
```

This will fix