# dyld: Symbol not found: _OPENSSL_init_ssl

Tags: macos, openssl, homebrew, macos-mojave

I just installed ffsend and wget via homebrew on my MacOS (Mojave 10.14.6), and when I run the command

> ffsend upload some_file.tgz

or

> wget some_url some_file.tgz

I get the following:

> dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _OPENSSL_init_ssl 
>   Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/ffsend   Expected in:
>   /usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib/libssl.1.1.dylib
>
> dyld: Symbol not found: _OPENSSL_init_ssl   Referenced from:
>   /usr/local/bin/ffsend   Expected in:
>   /usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib/libssl.1.1.dylib
>
> Abort trap: 6

I know I've had some bugs with Open SSL previously, but I have no idea of how to tackle this problem.

Thanks

Comment: You will have better luck [here](https://github.com/timvisee/ffsend/issues) I suspect.

Comment: I will eventually post an issue there, I'm just not sure it's really related to ffsend (but rather to my openssl install).

Comment: Well homebrew deals with all those dependencies for you.

Comment: I think the problem is with homebrew/openssl (maybe some conflict?). See my update.

Comment: Did you give installing OpenSSL again a try? `brew install openssl`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was due to a conflict between versions of OpenSSL. Some programs (wget, ffsend) needed the latest version of OpenSSL, while some other programs (not distributed) needed an older version of OpenSSL, namely 1.0.2.

I found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59006602/dyld-library-not-loaded-usr-local-opt-openssl-lib-libssl-1-0-0-dylib): after reinstalling openssl via `brew reinstall openssl@1.1`, I used `brew switch openssl 1.0.2q`.

This way I can use both programs that need the latest version and those that use the older one.