# digest library issue for rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I am using `ruby 2.4.6` for an old project. Last time, I updated it was 5 months aggo and it worked well. Now, when I run `rails s`, I get this error messagge

```
.rbenv/versions/2.4.6/lib/ruby/2.4.0/digest.rb:16:in `const_missing': library not found for class Digest::SHA1 -- digest/sha1 (LoadError)
```

Someone has an idea ?

Answer (score 0):

This was related to an `openssl` issue. Following this SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59006602/dyld-library-not-loaded-usr-local-opt-openssl-lib-libssl-1-0-0-dylib). I ran

```
brew switch openssl 1.0.2s
```

and checked

```
ruby -r digest/sha1 -e 'p Digest::SHA1'
```

which correctly outputs `Digest::SHA1`