# macOs Big Sur -> 11.1? dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib

Tags: mongodb, openssl

When i dump from mongodb through the mongodump command then it's returning me error.

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/mongodump
Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6
```

I tried to fixing many times through the uninstalling and reinstalling using these commands

```
brew update && brew upgrade
brew reinstall openssl
```

Openssl version

```
  -> ls -al /usr/local/Cellar/openssl*
drwxr-xr-x   3 mukesh  staff   96 Dec 23 21:40 .
drwxrwxr-x  24 mukesh  admin  768 Dec 23 21:40 ..
drwxr-xr-x  14 mukesh  staff  448 Dec 23 21:40 1.1.1i
```

macOs version ->macOs Big Sur -> 11.1

Comment: Solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65494858/4593376

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the correct version of libssl for Big Sur is 1.1 or 1.1.1

This means that the issue lies with mongodb. Try updating that.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same case when trying to use mongodump.

I found the issue is caused by I was using a very old version mongodump that required openSSL1

```
/usr/local/bin/mongodump -> /usr/local/Cellar/mongodb/3.6.4/bin/mongodump
```

and that was installed on 2018

```
drwxr-xr-x  8 ****  admin   256B Apr 27  2018 3.6.4
```

The action I toke to fix it is to install the lastest version of mongodb-database-tools, and point mongodump to it.

```
brew install mongodb-database-tools
```

to make it:

```
lrwxr-xr-x  1 *****  staff  54 Oct  7 17:16 /usr/local/bin/mongodump -> ../Cellar/mongodb-database-tools/100.8.0/bin/mongodump
```

And it works.