# dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/php5/lib/libssh2.1.dylib

Tags: php, macos, curl, homebrew

The problem in a nutshell:

```
curl --v
```

results into:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/php5/lib/libssh2.1.dylib 
Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/curl 
Reason: image not found
```

On MacOS Big Sur 11.2.1.
So there are two questions:

1. How can I fix it?
2. (Just out of curiosity) How come a system installed curl depends on php5?

Solutions that didn't work:

1. `brew update && brew upgrade`
2. `brew install curl` & `brew reinstall curl`
3. Everything from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59006602/dyld-library-not-loaded-usr-local-opt-openssl-lib-libssl-1-0-0-dylib) and [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65494858/532551) in particular

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

```
brew install libssh2
brew link libssh2
```

which required

```
brew link --overwrite libssh2
```

in my case. But that did the trick.

Obviously, libssh2 link was outdated.

Comment: this solution is not solve my problem. Do you have other solutions?