# how to fix libgit2 after brew upgrade

Tags: homebrew, ls, libgit2

On Mac OS 13.2, in `zsh`, `ls` returns the following error message:

```
dyld[15164]: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/libgit2/lib/libgit2.1.6.dylib
  Referenced from: <14346135-E664-31AF-A80B-05A5335ED5D7> /usr/local/Cellar/exa/0.10.1_1/bin/exa
  Reason: tried: '/usr/local/opt/libgit2/lib/libgit2.1.6.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/usr/local/opt/libgit2/lib/libgit2.1.6.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/opt/libgit2/lib/libgit2.1.6.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libgit2.1.6.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libgit2.1.6.dylib' (no such file, not in dyld cache), '/usr/local/Cellar/libgit2/1.7.2/lib/libgit2.1.6.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/usr/local/Cellar/libgit2/1.7.2/lib/libgit2.1.6.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/Cellar/libgit2/1.7.2/lib/libgit2.1.6.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libgit2.1.6.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libgit2.1.6.dylib' (no such file, not in dyld cache)
zsh: abort      exa -1 --classify --group-directories-first
```

This seems to have started happening after a Homebrew upgrade.

I had hoped [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59184347/8510347) would be what I needed, but I could modify it to work for my case.

How can I fix this problem?

## Update

Somehow the problem seems to be that the version of libgit2 in that directory is a more recent one but everything is still calling the old version: I went `cd /usr/local/opt/libgit2/lib/` and found (using the Finder, not `ls` of course) that this directory contains `libgit2.1.7.2.dylib` but no `libgit2.1.6.dylib`. Maybe I should just make a symlink for that old version? Or would that cause other problems?

I tried `brew unlink libgit2` then `brew link libgit2`; I tried `brew uninstall libgit2` then `brew install libgit2; and I tried installing the latest Command Line Tools, restarting the computer, etc. But I still have this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one answer that I just tried, which worked, though I am not sure it is the best way to do this:

I did what I described in the "Update" to my question, namely `cd /usr/local/opt/libgit2/lib/` followed by `ln -s libgit2.1.7.2.dylib libgit2.1.6.dylib`. Now `ls` is working again.

But is that the right way to fix this issue? It feels a bit like a hack that might cause other problems.